# Firebase ver9 adjustment of snapshop/sub collection in React

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to replace below code (ver8) to firebase SDK ver9 (modular style). but no success so far.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = db
      .collection("posts")
      .doc("postId")
      .collection("comments")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
         //update some state
      });
    return () => {
      unsub();
    };
  }, []);
```

I tried to use query to access this sub collection together with orderBy by refer to following official example but couldn't find working solution, especially how to handle sub collection reference in query. (how can I realize "collection().doc().collection().orderBy().onSnapshot" in ver9 ?)

I'm really appreciated if someone give me a hint. BR

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see in the documentation for the [`collection` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#collection), you can pass in the entire path as a string.

So that should be something like:

```
...
const db = getFirestore();
const commentsRef = doc(db, "posts", postId, "comments");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Frank-san Thank you very much for your hint. Now everything working fine with full path arguments (your hint) as like below.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, "posts", props.postId, "comments"),
      orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
    );
    const unSub = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
          //Some process
    });
    return () => {
      unSub();
    };
  }, []);
```

Thanks again and have a good day !